# How do call instructions get generated for imported functions in a compiled module

Tags: windows, assembly, import, module

I am not sure if I am phrasing the question correctly, but basically I want to know how the call instruction is generated when calling an imported function from another library.

For example

```
GetModuleFileName(...)
```

is compiled to

```
call 0x4D0000
```

where 0x4D0000 is the address of the imported function which is dynamic.

How does windows set those calls and would it be possible to circumvent it and set a custom address instead.

Comment: The term you are looking for is called *relocation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address used in the call statement isn't dynamic. It's a relative address that's fixed at link time like a call to any other function. That's because the call is actually to a stub, and the stub performs an indirect jump to the real function. The indirect jump uses a memory operand that refers to location in the import table.  When the executable (or DLL) is loaded by Windows it updates the import table with addresses of all the functions the executable or DLL uses in any DLLs it's linked to.

So if an executable a call instruction like this:

```
    call _GetModuleFileNameA@12
```

Then somewhere else in the same executable is astub like this:

```
_GetModuleFileNameA@12:
    jmp  [__imp__GetModuleFileNameA@12]
```

And somewhere in the import table there is a definition like this:

```
__imp__GetModuleFileNameA@12:
    DD    ?
```

Windows sets the value of `__imp_GetModuleFileName@12` in the import table when the executable (or DLL) is loaded.  There's not much you can do change this, though it's not too hard to change the value after the executable (or DLL) has been loaded. Note that the import table might be located in a read-only section, meaning you may need to change the virtual memory protections in order to do this.